# onclick on image is not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to display some info when a user clicks on an image. Here is the image tag

```
<img src="<? echo $list[image]; ?>" onclick="showUser(<?php echo $list['id']; ?>)">
```

I am directly using the example from w3schools. Here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Is there something i am doing wrong? When I click the image nothing happens.

Comment: W3Schools - *That's* the problem.

Comment: Did you define the showUser function in your code?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console???

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just figured out the problem the second I posted this question. I was referencing the filepath wrong. @David W#Schools is not the problem. It's a great site for beginners.

Comment: @khuderm w3schools is riddled with grave errors. Enough to make some people create a site rallying against it: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @khuderm You should either delete your question, or post the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Could you show us showUser function? There may be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself. In my showUsers function when I call `xmlHttp.open` I had the path to my file wrong. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using that GET method, it would be better to use a load method instead because you would have less code to work with and in my opinion it would make things easier. Now here's how I would do it.
Assuming you got that code from there, this is what you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ShowUser(str) {$(function) {
  $('#loadhere').load("thepagetoloadfrom.php?q="+str);
}};
</script>
```

`#loadhere` is where you want to load the output from the load().
This is much shorter and easier to understand I believe.

Comment: @WDever Thanks for the suggested edit, I often forget because I copy / paste and edit my code to write less, which is bad practice.